# Gatsby build failing on mozjpeg

Tags: node.js, linux, docker, npm, gatsby

From yesterday I am unable to deploy my Gatsby site to our server, build is complaining about mozjpeg library. Have anyone encountered this error before?

I tried:

- locking gatsby-cli
- adding `automake` linux package
- adding `libtools` linux package
- unfreezing yarn lock
- installing dependencies without lock file

But nothing seemed to help, the error is as follows:

```
error /node_modules/mozjpeg: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node lib/install.js
Arguments:
Directory: /node_modules/mozjpeg
Output:
⚠ spawn /node_modules/mozjpeg/vendor/cjpeg ENOENT
⚠ mozjpeg pre-build test failed
ℹ compiling from source
✖ Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c ./configure --enable-static --disable-shared --disable-dependency-tracking --with-jpeg8 --prefix="/node_modules/mozjpeg/vendor" --bindir="/node_modules/mozjpeg/vendor" --libdir="/node_modules/mozjpeg/vendor"
```

**OS**
Ubuntu 16.04.6
**Node**
12.14
**Gatsby**
2.19.7

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to some GitHub threads:

- https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/1271
- https://github.com/mozilla/mozjpeg/issues/244
- https://github.com/imagemin/imagemin/issues/168

They suggest to:

- Installing `nasm` (highly recommended)
- If the solution above doesn't work, install `automake`, `autoconf`, `libtool`, `dpkg`, `pkgconfig`, `libpng`, `libpng-dev`, `g++`
- Remove cache

Comment: A combination of all solved it! I did visited all the links before, but cache was missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The same issue arises when deploying to to GitLab pages using the docker `image: "node:lts-alpine"`. It fails because `yarn:install` cannot build `mozjpeg`.

> error /builds/my_project/gatsby/node_modules/mozjpeg: Command failed.

To fix it, add these lines to `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
before_script:
   - apk add make nasm autoconf automake libtool dpkg pkgconfig libpng libpng-dev g++
```

#### Expected result

```
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
Done in 170.33s.
Saving cache for successful job
00:27
Creating cache master-1...
node_modules/: found 82747 matching files and directories 
WARNING: .cache/: no matching files                
WARNING: public/: no matching files                
Uploading cache.zip to https://storage.googleapis.com/gitlab-com-runners-cache/project/...
Created cache
Cleaning up file based variables
00:01
Job succeeded
```

#### Actual result

```
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
error /builds/my_project/gatsby/node_modules/mozjpeg: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node lib/install.js
Arguments: 
Directory: /builds/my_project/gatsby/node_modules/mozjpeg
Output:
⚠ spawn /builds/my_project/gatsby/node_modules/mozjpeg/vendor/cjpeg ENOENT
  ⚠ mozjpeg pre-build test failed
  ℹ compiling from source
  ✖ Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c autoreconf -fiv
/bin/sh: autoreconf: not found
    at /builds/my_project/gatsby/node_modules/bin-build/node_modules/execa/index.js:231:11
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
Cleaning up file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

#### Environment

OS information from: `image: "node:lts-alpine"`

`package.json` information:

```
  npmPackages:
    gatsby: ^2.31.1 => 2.31.1
    gatsby-image: ^2.10.0 => 2.10.0
    gatsby-plugin-manifest: ^2.11.0 => 2.11.0
    gatsby-plugin-material-ui: ^2.1.10 => 2.1.10
    gatsby-plugin-offline: ^3.9.0 => 3.9.0
    gatsby-plugin-react-helmet: ^3.9 => 3.9.0
    gatsby-plugin-sharp: ^2.13.4 => 2.13.4
    gatsby-source-filesystem: ^2.10.0 => 2.10.0
    gatsby-theme-firebase: ^1.0.10 => 1.0.10
    gatsby-transformer-sharp: ^2.11.0 => 2.11.0
  npmGlobalPackages:
    gatsby-cli: 2.17.0
```

Comment: Note that `make` is needed, so if it's not in the docker image, it must be installed.

Answer (score -1):

I just went through this same issue on Alpine in a Dockerfile. Turns out that what it needed was everything that you'd typically need to build from source. Alpine has a package called `alpine-apk` that I added to the Dockerfile. This fixed all subsequent issues that I had with `mozjpeg`. I realize that the original poster isn't running Alpine but I wanted this to get posted somewhere so that another person with this issue has.