# What are the dependencies of `gatsby-plugin-sharp` and `mozjpeg`?

Tags: gatsby, github-actions, sharp, mozjpeg

There's an issue with `gatsby-plugin-sharp` (or more specifically sub-dependency `mozjpeg`) whereby it'll give the exception `autoreconf: not found`, but the issue is actually with other dependencies. There are various posts where people have found one combination or another of various dependencies to get it to work for them (eg https://stackoverflow.com/a/66170062/2475012, https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/19432#issuecomment-553644600). But there doesn't seem to be a definitive list anywhere of the exact dependencies you need.

I'm running Gatsby on GitHub Actions on `ubuntu-latest`. My `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "matt.si",
  "private": false,
  "description": "Mattsi Jansky's personal blog",
  "author": "Mattsi Jansky",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gatsby build",
    "dev": "gatsby develop",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:updateSnapshots": "jest --updateSnapshot",
    "test:visual": "yarn build && ./scripts/run-visual-regression-tests.sh",
    "test:visual:update": "docker-compose run visual-regression-tests reference",
    "test:visual:approve": "docker-compose run visual-regression-tests approve",
    "test:visual:report": "open tests/visual/backstop_data/html_report/index.html",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.jsx --ignore-pattern public ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-gatsby": "0.5.1",
    "gatsby": "2.24.87",
    "gatsby-image": "2.4.21",
    "gatsby-plugin-feed": "2.5.19",
    "gatsby-plugin-google-analytics": "2.3.19",
    "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "2.4.35",
    "gatsby-plugin-offline": "3.2.37",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "3.3.14",
    "gatsby-plugin-sass": "2.3.21",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "3.0.0",
    "gatsby-remark-footnotes": "0.0.7",
    "gatsby-remark-images": "3.3.39",
    "gatsby-remark-prismjs": "3.5.16",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "2.3.36",
    "gatsby-transformer-remark": "2.8.46",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "2.5.20",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "3.0.0",
    "node-sass": "4.14.1",
    "prismjs": "1.22.0",
    "prop-types": "15.7.2",
    "react": "16.14.0",
    "react-dom": "16.14.0",
    "react-helmet": "6.1.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.14.0",
    "rehype-react": "6.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "26.6.1",
    "enzyme": "3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "1.15.5",
    "eslint": "7.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.21.5",
    "jest": "26.6.1",
    "wait-on": "5.2.0"
  },
  "license": "GPL-3.0-only"
}
```

The relevant parts of the GitHub Actions definition:

```
name: Run tests
on: [push]

jobs:
  build:
    name: Run Tests
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v1
      
      - name: Install System Dependencies
        run: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install make nasm autoconf automake libtool dpkg pkg-config libpng-dev g++

      - name: Install Project Dependencies
        uses: borales/actions-yarn@v2.1.0
        with:
          cmd: install
```

It fails with `autoreconf: not found` at the `Install Project Dependencies` step. I tried adding `autoreconf` to the `Install System Dependencies` step, but it was already the latest version. I tried `buildessentials`, but it was also already the latest version. I added `libvips-dev`, which seems to be the name of the `libvips` library in `apt-get`, and that one did install. After looking up the same issue with `mozjpeg` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/64927666/2475012) I added `sudo apt-get install make nasm autoconf automake libtool dpkg pkg-config libpng-dev g++`. But all of those other than `nasm` already existed.

But every time I still got the `autoreconf: not found` issue. Specifically, the full error (https://github.com/Mattsi-Jansky/matt.si/runs/2051073618):

```
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
error /github/workspace/node_modules/mozjpeg: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node lib/install.js
Arguments: 
Directory: /github/workspace/node_modules/mozjpeg
Output:
⚠ spawn /github/workspace/node_modules/mozjpeg/vendor/cjpeg ENOENT
  ⚠ mozjpeg pre-build test failed
  ℹ compiling from source
  ✖ Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c autoreconf -fiv
/bin/sh: autoreconf: not found


    at /github/workspace/node_modules/bin-build/node_modules/execa/index.js:231:11
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

So I'm at a loss. I suppose my questions are: a) Am I following the right thread here, trying to find the right dependencies? b) What exactly are the dependencies I should be adding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed by replacing usages of `borales/actions-yarn` with [setup node](https://github.com/actions/setup-node), which includes Yarn.

`borales/actions-yarn` was intended for the GitHub Actions beta, and isn't the recommended way of running yarn actions. They run in some legacy way. I'm not too clear on the details, but I think what was happening was that the `borales/actions-yarn` was running on a separate image that didn't have the dependencies installed.

Answer (score 0):

`gatsby-plugin-sharp`, according to the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gatsby-plugin-sharp):

- [`@babel/runtime`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/%40babel%2Fruntime)
- [`async`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async)
- [`bluebird`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bluebird)
- [`filenamify`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/filenamify)
- [`fs-extra`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra)
- [`gatsby-core-utils`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gatsby-core-utils)
- [`gatsby-telemetry`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gatsby-telemetry)
- [`got`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got)
- [`imagemin`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gatsby-plugin-sharp#:%7E:text=got-,imagemin,-imagemin)
- [`imagemin-mozjpeg`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/imagemin-mozjpeg)
- [`imagemin-pngquant`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/imagemin-pngquant)
- [`lodash`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash)
- [`mini-svg-data-uri`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mini-svg-data-uri)
- [`potrace`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/potrace)
- [`prob-image-size`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/probe-image-size)
- [`progress`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/progress)
- [`semver`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/semver)
- [`sharp`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharp)
- [`svgo`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svgo)
- [`uuid`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid)
- Dev dependencies: [`@babel/cli`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/%40babel%2Fcli), [`@babel/core`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/%40babel%2Fcore), [`@types/sharp`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/%40types%2Fsharp), [`babel-preset-gatsby-package`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-gatsby-package), [`cross-env`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env), [`gatsby-plugin-image`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gatsby-plugin-image), [`gatsby-plugin-utils`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gatsby-plugin-utils)

On the other side, [`mozjpeg`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mozjpeg) has:

- [`bin-build`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bin-build)
- [`bin-wrapper`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bin-wrapper)
- [`logalot`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/logalot)
- Dev dependencies: [`ava`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ava), [`bin-check`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bin-check), [`compare-size`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/compare-size), [`execa`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/execa), [`tempy`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tempy), [`xo`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xo)

Comment: I don't think this is complete. These are all the dependencies that NPM is aware of, but during `mozjpeg`'s install step it tries to compile something which depends on a number of libraries and build tools on the host machine. Such as `make`, `nasm`, `autoconf`, `automake`, `libtool`, `dpkg`, `pkg-config`, `libpng-dev`, and `g++`. These are dependencies you can't install `mozjpeg` without, but aren't NPM dependencies.

Comment: It's what NPM package says, it's not a matter of complete, is what the NPM documentation itself says... Those are auxiliary dependencies, may be required for other modules or the dev-dependencies themselves. Can you clarify the scope of the question a little bit more?

Comment: They're dependencies that you can't successfully install `mozjpeg` without. NPM may have resolved its dependencies, but when `mozjpeg`'s post-install script is call it tries to build itself from source and fails. Most information I can find about this online indicates it's due to missing build dependencies needed for building from source. Specifically because we see `compiling from source` in the error output it must go wrong around here: https://github.com/imagemin/mozjpeg-bin/blob/a1f4d1c729657e904481df4204bf5ead68e0c890/lib/install.js#L15